# Compositional data - interpreting Dirichlet regression with interactions

Tags: compositional-data, dirichlet-regression

I did a Dirichlet Regression to assess the effect of independent variables on a compositional dependent variable. However, as I have 3 predictors, I do get interaction.
I have a hard time understanding the results with an interaction mindset. Since in a regression, there is one reference level, I'm confused with the conclusion of my analysis (i.e. what am I seeing ?). I feel like something is missing... like a post hoc

In short, this is a 2[FT/FA --> within-subject]x2[oui, non --> between subject] x3 [NoFB, GoodFB, AccurateFB --> within subject] design with a 4 level dependant variable (Med, Low, VL, UL)

**Study objective**: to look at the effect of FB on the dependent variable. To see if the effect is modulated by factor [oui, non] (i.e. interaction). We expect to see an effect of FB under the Oui factor, but not under the Non factor.

Here are the results

```
 Family: dirichlet 
  Links: muLow = logit; muVL = logit; muUL = logit; phi = identity 
Formula: cbind(Med, Low, VL, UL) ~ Feet * Realized * FB + (1 | Participant) 
   Data: WaveletML (Number of observations: 747) 
  Draws: 4 chains, each with iter = 2000; warmup = 1000; thin = 1;
         total post-warmup draws = 4000

Group-Level Effects: 
~Participant (Number of levels: 25) 
                    Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
sd(muLow_Intercept)     0.06      0.04     0.00     0.14 1.00     1061     1508
sd(muVL_Intercept)      0.22      0.05     0.14     0.32 1.00     1599     2537
sd(muUL_Intercept)      0.34      0.06     0.25     0.48 1.01     1230     2216

Population-Level Effects: 
                                  Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
muLow_Intercept                       0.87      0.10     0.68     1.06 1.00     1092     2069
muVL_Intercept                        0.51      0.11     0.28     0.73 1.00     1226     2181
muUL_Intercept                        1.07      0.12     0.83     1.33 1.01      830     1526
muLow_FeetFT                          0.27      0.14    -0.00     0.54 1.00      927     1731
muLow_Realizedoui                    -0.03      0.17    -0.35     0.31 1.00      894     1872
muLow_FBGoodFB                        0.09      0.14    -0.17     0.37 1.00      996     1814
muLow_FBNoFB                         -0.06      0.13    -0.32     0.21 1.00     1169     2071
muLow_FeetFT:Realizedoui             -0.10      0.23    -0.56     0.35 1.00      851     1693
muLow_FeetFT:FBGoodFB                -0.08      0.20    -0.46     0.30 1.00      889     1579
muLow_FeetFT:FBNoFB                  -0.08      0.19    -0.47     0.29 1.00     1029     1855
muLow_Realizedoui:FBGoodFB           -0.34      0.22    -0.77     0.09 1.00      856     1635
muLow_Realizedoui:FBNoFB             -0.15      0.22    -0.59     0.27 1.00      989     2200
muLow_FeetFT:Realizedoui:FBGoodFB     0.41      0.32    -0.22     1.02 1.00      858     1521
muLow_FeetFT:Realizedoui:FBNoFB       0.37      0.32    -0.26     1.01 1.00      978     1863
**muVL_FeetFT                           0.71      0.14     0.43     0.98 1.00     1002     1947**
muVL_Realizedoui                      0.00      0.19    -0.35     0.38 1.00     1005     2002
muVL_FBGoodFB                         0.12      0.14    -0.16     0.40 1.00     1086     1813
muVL_FBNoFB                          -0.16      0.14    -0.44     0.11 1.00     1210     2370
muVL_FeetFT:Realizedoui              -0.30      0.24    -0.78     0.17 1.00      892     1802
muVL_FeetFT:FBGoodFB                 -0.23      0.20    -0.61     0.17 1.00     1001     2020
muVL_FeetFT:FBNoFB                    0.06      0.20    -0.32     0.45 1.00     1173     1969
**muVL_Realizedoui:FBGoodFB            -0.86      0.24    -1.34    -0.41 1.00     1012     1730**
muVL_Realizedoui:FBNoFB              -0.30      0.23    -0.75     0.15 1.00     1073     1847
**muVL_FeetFT:Realizedoui:FBGoodFB      0.68      0.33     0.02     1.30 1.00      969     1712**
muVL_FeetFT:Realizedoui:FBNoFB        0.62      0.33    -0.03     1.26 1.00     1021     1942
muUL_FeetFT                           0.13      0.14    -0.14     0.40 1.00      860     1541
muUL_Realizedoui                      0.18      0.21    -0.21     0.61 1.00      762     1648
muUL_FBGoodFB                        -0.00      0.13    -0.25     0.25 1.00      949     1812
muUL_FBNoFB                          -0.12      0.13    -0.37     0.14 1.00     1105     2358
muUL_FeetFT:Realizedoui              -0.04      0.22    -0.48     0.39 1.00      841     1652
muUL_FeetFT:FBGoodFB                 -0.11      0.19    -0.49     0.27 1.00      913     1704
muUL_FeetFT:FBNoFB                    0.30      0.19    -0.08     0.67 1.00     1006     1986
**muUL_Realizedoui:FBGoodFB            -1.07      0.22    -1.49    -0.64 1.00      909     1651**
**muUL_Realizedoui:FBNoFB              -0.51      0.21    -0.93    -0.12 1.00      951     2264**
muUL_FeetFT:Realizedoui:FBGoodFB      0.59      0.32    -0.04     1.20 1.00      915     1720
muUL_FeetFT:Realizedoui:FBNoFB        0.51      0.31    -0.09     1.12 1.00     1025     2002

Family Specific Parameters: 
    Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
phi    11.34      0.33    10.71    11.99 1.00     5405     3008




Draws were sampled using sampling(NUTS). For each parameter, Bulk_ESS
and Tail_ESS are effective sample size measures, and Rhat is the potential
scale reduction factor on split chains (at convergence, Rhat = 1).
```

Based on my result, I have a significant (i.e. 95% CrI do not cross 0) interaction for muUL_Realizedoui:FBNoFB and muUL_Realizedoui:FBGoodFB. But what is it telling me? Ok, yes, the slop is different when we compared it to the reference, but is there more?

So, for now, I can conclude that, in relation to the reference, there is a decreased contribution of UL under the NoFB and GoodFB condition with the oui factor compared to the UL contribution under the ErroneousFB/non condition. However, there is no information as to if the UL contribution was different for ErroneousFB under the Oui factor compared to NoFB and GoodFB still under the oui factor.

So in short, I have the feeling that many comparisons are missing from the Dirichlet regression and I have a hard time getting a clear picture of the effect of FB and Oui/Non on the dependent variable. It might only be my post-hoc mindset that needs to be updated!

Any input on how I can understand these results?
Thanks !